# Using a PHP file in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, json

Good day
I am writing a website that must use a php file from a server and display it into HTML table. The PHP file generates a JSON Array and have the following output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Description] => Bacon, feta and avo panini
        [Order_Number] => 7111
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Description] => Bacon, feta and avo panini
        [Order_Number] => 7112
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Description] => Cheese, ham and pineapple panini
        [Order_Number] => 7111
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Description] => Cheese, ham and pineapple panini
        [Order_Number] => 7112
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Description] => Grilled cheese panini
        [Order_Number] => 7111
    )
```

My question is how do I display the data into a html table that gives 2 columns called **description** and **Order Number**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Iterate over array with `foreach` and output data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Order_Number</th>
  </tr>
<?php
foreach ($yourArry as $row)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row["Description"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["Order_Number"]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

the idea here inside your .php file write your HTML code with ordinary but way inside the table here is comes the logic of php I just did a foreach loop inside your json array and echo the row element as long with the data

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot and solved my problem.